# How to completely remove objects from the scene with a script?

Tags: python, objects

Using blender 2.79, I'm trying to clean the blender scene from created objects.

Objects disappear, all counters are OK, but adding new objects into scene lag the same way as no objects were killed.
I use this approach:

```
objects_created = []
cnt = 0

# source is some source which generates data items to create meshes
source_item = source.get_next()
while source_item:

    # create a mesh data
    name, bm = bmesh_from_source_item(source_item)
    source_item = source.get_next()

    mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(name)
    bm.to_mesh(mesh)
    # create an object with this mesh data
    obj = bpy.data.objects.new(name, mesh)
    # link it to the scene
    bpy.context.scene.objects.link(obj)
    # and store the reference to kill it later
    objects_created.append(obj)
    
    cnt += 1
    
    if cnt % MY_CHUNK_SIZE == 0:
    
        # process created objects (say, export them to fbx)
        process_objects(objects_created)
        # and delete them one by one in reversed order
        while len(objects_created):
            obj = objects_created.pop()
            obj_data = obj.data
            # first the object
            bpy.data.objects.remove(obj)
            # then its data
            bpy.data.meshes.remove(obj_data)

        # even updating the scene
        bpy.context.scene.update()
        # and even force GC to perform 
        gc.collect()
```

Adding objects speed degrades as total object count increases.
So, the idea is to process objects in chunks to speed things up.

But after cleaning objects this way, there is no speed improvements on next chunk items creating at all!

It seems that (data.objects, data.meshes, scene.objects) are not everything to address here.

So, What am I missing here?

Comment: I'm assuming you're running this on a low spec computer. The bmesh data will still be in memory. Try `bm.free` after `bm.to_mesh(mesh)` to free up that memory

Comment: Thank you. I added bm.free(). Memory maybe now is better, but it's still as slow as before, so there is something else that is somehow growing. :-(

Comment: Why process then in "chunks"? Why not just one at a time?

Comment: The entire dataset is about 135 000 items. Chunks are 10 000. The speed degrades fast. First 500 items are handled in about 3 seconds. After 5000, the same 500 take 20+ seconds. The more, the worse. So, chunks is my hope to process them all as fast as we (blender and I) can.

Comment: Well, it sounds like a memory issue. Does your memory keep increasing? May not even be a Blender issue, might be a Windows memory issue as Windows is notorious for not freeing used memory in some cases. (assuming you're using Windows)

Comment: Yes, I run it under windows. According to task manager, there is no substantial memory growth. When it starts to slow down, there is enough free RAM (gigs). It looks like blender registers something, which has bad access time on its elements. Maybe it's something to do with blender's undo system (?). Anyway it looks like a major design flaw. Now I'd rather give it up, and consider blend file reload, as a last resort. BTW I never faced windows memory leaks which were caused not by the user level programs, but the windows core itself.

Comment: Blenders undo is limited exactly for that reason, but might be worth checking how many undo levels you have. Preferences -> System -> Memory and Limits. Try dialing it back to 1 and see how you go?

Comment: No, setting undo_steps=2 (it's minimal value the UI allows to set), and even disabling 'Global undo' (use_global_undo=False) flag changes nothing.
Hope, that it would be enough to just reload the file with something like bpy.ops.wm.revert_mainfile(), and not to restart the process completely. Assuming that I'm inside the Operator.execute() myself :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that there is no reliable way to clean the scene up without reloading the .blend file.
So, I ended up with this approach. It's not a trivial task as well, but it works, though.

if someone will find it interesting, the code is in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75500428/2131659).